# Unable to play-pause using gst-play command on raspberry pi 2

Tags: gstreamer, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to play an audio file using gst-play command on my raspberry pi 2 running on raspbian distro:

```
gst-play-1.0 myfile.mp3 --interactive --audiosink=alsasink
```

The command was working fine until Pi's OS crashed. I had a backup image so I didn't have to reinstall Gstreamer. But now when I pause and resume, it hangs. I am using Gstreamer 1.4.4. I am pretty sure all the necessary plugins are installed. How can I resolve this? What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that gst-play works fine when i am logged in as root but it hangs when i am logged in as user pi. I tried to debug with GST_DEBUG=3 and strace, separately as root and pi. But I found similar errors. The logs can be found in this [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwBzTeIBZ--HLU9ydFl0Tm9SeGM&usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can start debugging with `GST_DEBUG=3 gst-play ...` then you can put higher value like 4 etc.. you can also do

```
export GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=`pwd`
```

and check the generated dot graph (gstreamer will autogenerate dot graphs in various time point) with:

```
dot somegraph.dot -Tpng -o graph.png
```

Comment: I checked the generated graph but I could not find the problem. The weird thing which i noticed recently is that, when i login as the "root", gst-play works fine. When i login as the user "pi", i face problems with gst-play. Logging in as pi and using sudo does not work either.

Comment: @Luffy then check logs with GST_DEBUG.. and find differences between running as root and running as pi.. if you find something suspicious, paste it to the question as UPDATE..